# Define a constant and use it on all pages

Tags: php, path, constants

I use `index.php` as routing page.

I'd like to:

```
define('ROOT_DIR', __DIR__);
```

on `index.php` and use `ROOT_DIR` in all pages, is it possible without including nothing else?

Or is this the only way?

1) Create a file `globals.php` on the DOCUMENT_ROOT directory

2) `define('ROOT_DIR', __DIR__);` in `globals.php`

3) Include `globals.php` in every page of the site to use `ROOT_DIR`:

```
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/globals.php';
```

Which are the advantages using a constant?

Isn't it simplier to use always `__DIR__`?

Can you please tell me which is definitively the best and most usefull method to manage path when including files, etc. on `php`?

Thank you!

**EDIT - FINAL SOLUTION?**

1) Create a file `globals.php` e.g. on `/WEB/mysite/htdocs/includes/`

2) On `globals.php` define a constant with: `define('ROOT_DIR', __DIR__);`

3) On every file of the site `include 'globals.php';`. Eg. if I want to include `globals.php` on `/WEB/mysite/htdocs/test/header.php` I'll use `include '../includes/globals.php`

4) On every include on every file use
`include ROOT_DIR.'/path_to_file_relative_to_ROOT_DIR/file.php'`

5) E.g. to include `/WEB/mysite/htdocs/scripts/script1.php` on `/WEB/mysite/htdocs/test/header.php` I'll write:

```
include '../includes/globals.php';
include ROOT_DIR.'/../scripts/script1.php';
```

And never change the path of `globals.php;`

**EDIT2 USING INDEX AS ROUTING PAGE**

.htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

index.php used as routing page:

```
<?php
include 'globals.php';

$uri = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$trimmeduri = trim($uri, '/');

if($uri == '/'){
    $sigle = $link->query("SELECT sigla AS lingue FROM LINGUE");

    while($lingue_db = mysqli_fetch_array($sigle)){
        $lingue[] = $lingue_db['lingue'];
    }

    $client_lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);

    if(in_array($client_lang, $lingue)){
        header("location: http://www.mysite.com/$client_lang/index.php");
    }else{
        header("location: http://www.mysite.com/it/index.php");
    }

}else{
    include "sql.php";
    $link = new mysqli($host, $user, $pw, $db);
    $link->set_charset('UTF8');
    $trimmeduri = $link->real_escape_string($trimmeduri);
    $urlliste = $link->query("SELECT Nome FROM LISTE WHERE URL = '$trimmeduri'");
    while($urllista = mysqli_fetch_array($urlliste)){
        $lista = $urllista['Nome'];
    }
    $uri_count = mysqli_num_rows($urlliste);
    $urlliste->close();

    if($uri_count == '1'){
        header("location: http://www.mysite.com/pages/page.php?name=$lista");
    }elseif($uri_count > '1'){
        header('HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request', true, 400);
        require_once "errors/400badrequest.html";
    }else{
        header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
        require_once "errors/404notfound.php";
    }
}
?>
```

The problem is that the constant defined on globals.php is not avaiable on the other pages... Why?

Comment: "Can you please tell me which is definitively the best and most usefull method to manage path when including files, etc. on php?" no one as programming just as life, there are no absolutes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want code to be executed on every page, you have to make sure it's executed on every page. Easiest way to ensure that is to put it in a central file that's included from every page, that's what the `include` statement is for.

As for some of the big advantages of using constants:

1. You only have to change it one time if it changes, and all the thousands of references automatically take the new value.
2. Constants keep your code readable and devoid of 'magic numbers' etc. - it's easier to read code that references `MAXIMUM_SUPPORTED_LENGTH` than an arbitrary comparison with a number.
3. Constants can contain precalculated constants.

For the third: in your own sample, `dirname(__FILE__)` would actually result in a different value depending on the folder in which the invoking PHP script is located. Putting it into a constant eliminates that issue. Secondly, calling `dirname(__FILE__)` will actually internally:

1. Look up which file we are executed
2. Look up the `dirname` function and invoke it
3. Do some nasty string processing to determine the directory name

It's not terribly slow, but calling it 500 times is. And if the result is going to be the same 500 times anyway, why not do it once and store it in a constant for later reference? Makes the web page load faster in the end.

Finally - a completely offtopic remark, but relevant to your specific question - as of PHP 5.3.0 there is also a `__DIR__` constant which is literally defined to be identical to `dirname(__FILE__)`. [Read more about it here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php).

Comment: Thank you. So the best idea is to (if I correctly understanded): create a file `global.php` which defines `define('ROOT_DIR', __DIR__);` and include it in every file of the web site. My doubt now is, how should I include `global.php` on every page? With `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/path_to_/global.php` or with relative paths?

Comment: Use relative paths, `DOCUMENT_ROOT` has historically been less-than-reliable (Apache used to set it wrong for virtual document roots), and you can always count on relative paths to be valid within your own app regardless of deployment. Also, use `__DIR__` if your webserver is up to date (PHP 5.2 is outdated).

Comment: I updated my question with my "final solution"? Is all right? Should I use other expedients? Thank you very much!

Comment: Sounds good enough :)  As you progress with PHP you'll probably move onto more dynamic URL parsing, and as such your directory structures, but for now this'll do. You'll revisit the choice when you start parsing all URLs through the same root file ;)

Comment: Thank you... but now you plant me a seed of doubt... Where can I learn about parsing: by now I cannot understand what you mean with "parsing all URLs through the same root file"!

Comment: Use `FallbackResource` or `RewriteRule` in your `.htaccess` file to handle **all** URLs via a single `index.php` file in the root, then parse `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to determine from there what code to load and which response to serve. It's how all the common frameworks and big sites do it. Don't rush it though, this is an advanced approach, first learn the code, then learn how to master it.

Comment: If you mean to use index.php as a routing file, and redirect all request to index.php whit `.htaccess file` I do it already: on index.php I get the URI and then if it's `= '/'` I redirect to `/browserdesideredlanguage/index.php/`.

Comment: And why not then `include './includes/global.php';` from there?  ;)

Comment: Because it doesn't work to me until now... :( I don't know why! I updated my answer

Comment: Is there a big single error on my EDIT2 or is the problem so vast that I should start a new question?